# How to automatically check for stable release upgrades of Fedora at login?

Tags: fedora, dist-upgrade, motd

From what I can find, Fedora does not seem to have an `/etc/update-motd.d/` like Ubuntu-based systems. I do not want automatic updates (because I like to update manually), but I would like to be notified about the availability of a new release upgrade via the MOTD bulletin whenever I login to my machine using SSH.

Is that possible? If yes, how may I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Fedora uses `pam_motd`. I'm on mobile right now, so I can't help you atm. If no one has answered before I get home, I can help you as soon as I turn on my PC.

Comment: @telometto Thanks. I’ll look forward to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this. It looks like the function you are looking for is specific to Ubuntu. You could try to make a bash script yourself (sorry, but I don't know how to make one) or get a hold of the `update-notifier.deb` package and convert it an `.rpm` for Fedora using `alien`. Sorry that I can't be of more help.